# snowflake copy into table from S3

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

I am trying to do a simple import of an ASCII file in S3 to a snowflake table.   The number of columns in the ASCCI file is the same as the number of columns in the table.   I got this to work yesterday using an internal stage in Snowflake, but doing it from S3 doesn't seem to work.   Here is what I did:

```
  create or replace stage irdb_demo url='s3://irdbgenericdemodata'
  credentials=(aws_key_id='???' aws_secret_key='???');

  list @irdb_demo;
```

It returns one row:
1
s3://irdbgenericdemodata/PAM_PORTFOLIOS.CSV

I can type:
select t.$1, t.$2,t.$3,t.$4 from @irdb_demo  t;

and it returns the 26 rows that I expect, such as:

PAM
100
"GIC"
"Mod Scn Act/Act"
etc.

I give it the commands:

```
create or replace file format mycsvformat
type = 'CSV'
field_delimiter = ','
skip_header = 1
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"';


copy into Portfolios 
from @irdb_demo pattern='PAM_Portfolios.csv'
file_format=mycsvformat;
```

the result is:

Copy executed with 0 files processed.

When I type:

```
select * from irdb_generic.prod.portfolios;
```

I get no rows in the result.

if I type:
select * from irdb_generic.information_schema.load_history

I get no results from today.

What am I doing wrong with the command:

```
copy into Portfolios 
from @irdb_demo pattern='PAM_Portfolios.csv'
file_format=mycsvformat;
```

10/12/2020 update.

Snowflake support said the syntax should be:

copy into Portfolios from @irdb_demo pattern='.*PAM_Portfolios.csv.*' file_format=mycsvformat;

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: I can get this to work using this command:  
    copy into irdb_generic.prod.Portfolios 
    from @irdb_demo
     file_format=mycsvformat ;   because there is only one ascii file in the S3 bucket.   I want to tell it to only use the one file.

Answer (score 3):

To load just a specific file, you would need to use a FILES option rather than a pattern.

Example:

```
copy into load1 from @load1/
files=('test1.csv', 'test2.csv');
```

Reference: [copy_into](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `pattern` in your copy into statement, it tries to do the match on the entire file prefix and not just the prefix relative to the directory you have specified in your stage. So for your example the following will work since the pattern is matching against `irdbgenericdemodata/PAM_Portfolios.csv` and not just `/PAM_Portfolios.csv`:

```sql
copy into Portfolios 
from @irdb_demo pattern='.*PAM_Portfolios.csv'
file_format=mycsvformat;
```

I wouldn't really recommend this approach since if you have many files in your bucket it could take quite a while to match against every file. Instead, you could do something like this:

```sql
copy into Portfolios 
from @irdb_demo/PAM_Portfolios.csv
file_format=mycsvformat;
```

Or, as Abhi mentioned, you could use the `files` command to list them explicitly relative to the stage's location.